# How to redirect only when there is something after .html?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have found that there are some people with bad syntax links to our articles.

For example, we have an article with URL

http://www.oursite.com/demo/article-179.html

The issue is that lot of people have linked back to this article with bad syntax such as

http://www.oursite.com/demo/article-179.html%5Cohttp:/www.oursite.com/demo/glossary.php

Now, I added the following ReWrite Rule in the .htaccess file to take care of such links.

```
RewriteRule article-179\.html(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.oursite\.com\/demo\/article-179\.html [301,L]
```

But this has resulted in a **Redirect Loop** message. How can we fix this issue via htaccess rewrite rule. Basically, we need something in our rewrite rule that works only when there is one or more characters after the **.html**. If not, then it should not redirect.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

With best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` instead of `*`. `*` matches zero or more, which causes the pattern to match for the redirected path too, `+` instead matches one or more.

Also you should make the pattern as precise as possible, ie don't just check whether it ends with `article-179.html`, better check for the full path. And if this all happens on the same domain, then there's no need to use the absolute URL for the redirect.

There's also no need for escaping the substitution parameter like you did, it's treated as a simple string except for:

> - back-references ($N) to the RewriteRule pattern
> - back-references (%N) to the last matched RewriteCond pattern
> - server-variables as in rule condition test-strings (%{VARNAME})
> - mapping-function calls (${mapname:key|default})

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Long story short, theoretically this should do it:

```
RewriteRule ^demo/article-179\.html(.+)$ /demo/article-179.html [R=301,L]
```

or this if you really need the absolute URL:

```
RewriteRule ^demo/article-179\.html(.+)$ http://www.oursite.com/demo/article-179.html [R=301,L]
```